# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in serialport

Tags: php

I am currently having this problem where after my code loops twice while reading my data. At the same time, I am getting this error message also on my `dio_read` line.

```
$bbserialport=dio_open($portname, O_RWDR);
$runforseconds = new DateInterval("PT10S");
$endtime = (new DateTime())->add($runforseconds);
while(new DateTime() < endtime){
  $data = dio_read($bbserialport, 256);
   if($data){
      echoFlush("Data Received". $data);
   }
}
```

Comment: error is clear - what do you want from us?

Comment: I would like to know why there is an error message in dio_read line which states "maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" @Dagon

Comment: I suggest you start with the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)